# How to change the border color of loop group in plantuml?

Tags: plantuml

See, I have a loop in plantuml

```
loop 
    etl -> kafka:
    kafka -> linda:
    linda --> kafka: 
    kafka --> etl:
end
```

Now I want to change the border color of loop group from Black to DodgerBlue, neither

```
skinparam sequence {    
    SequenceGroupBorderColor DodgerBlue
}
```

nor

```
skinparam loop {
    SequenceGroupBorderColor DodgerBlue
}
```

works, the documentation work of PlantUML is so poor, I can hardly find any detail things, how to deal with this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following does work for me:

```
skinparam Sequence {
 GroupBorderColor #ff0000
}
```

and

```
skinparam {
 SequenceGroupBorderColor #ff0000
}
```

To get all possible skin parameters use:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar plantuml.jar  -language
```

and browse through the result.

See http://plantuml.com/skinparam for a small (incomplete) description of the skin parameters.

Edit: My initial: "Looks a bit like the color mnemonics don't work (maybe raise an issue at https://forum.plantuml.net/ask)" is not correct. I must have made a typo somewhere. retried with the comment from OP and it did work with DodgerBlue.

Comment: my fault, in the code I have posted, skinparam sequence {    
    SequenceGroupBorderColor DodgerBlue
} should be skinparam sequence {    
    GroupBorderColor DodgerBlue
}, thanks